# What could cause a flurry of Microsoft-Windows-Servicing events?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-event-log

I have a windows 2k8 machine that generated almost 40,000 WinEventLog:System events in the period of about 20 minutes.  The breakdown of these events by eventcode was approximately:

```
4373    46%
4371    46%
4383     7%
4372     1%
```

Microsoft-Windows-Servicing seemed to go crazy for a short time.... looking at updates, changing the state of updates etc.  What could have caused this?

UPDATE:
Many of the events seem to come in pairs of:

> Windows Servicing started a process of changing package KBfoobar state from Installed(Installed) to Installed(Installed)

and

> Windows Servicing successfully set package KBfoobar state to Installed(Intstalled)

Answer (score 1):

In one of my Windows 2008 SP2 servers, if I try to install/uninstall a feature (the add features wizard kicks in), it generates those event flood.

Answer (score 0):

All of those event ID's are classified as normal conditions with no further action required.  If you are getting them non-stop throughout the day then you have a deeper issue, if this server has just been installed or is going through a series of service updates it's to be expected.